# Can i change the Function of a Button or TextView at runtime?

Tags: android, onclick, runtime, textview

I put some OnClickListeners to wait for a TextView to be clicked and then write an X. Afterwards in the Code I create new OnClickListeners for those TextViews waiting for them to be pressed and then make the TextView write an O.

But for some reason it only writes X. So, I figured it's not possible to created a new OnClickListeners and to overwrite the old one at runtime. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are trying to create a tic tac toe app.

You don't need to create a new OnClickListener for writing "**X**" and "**O**" alternatively.

you can create a public variable. let us say char. and check its value before you pot X or O.

like this

```
public char myChar;

<<inside oncreate>>
{
//bla bla bla
char = "O"
}

<<inside onClick Method (View v)>>
if (myChar=="O"){
    myChar = "X"
}
else{
    myChar = "O"
}

if (v==editText1){
    editText1.setText(myChar)
}
```

Is this what you were looking for? or do you want actual Android code ?

Comment: Agreed. Changing listeners can lead to many problems (including memory leaks), it's a lot better practice to keep the same listener but make it do something dynamic. If you want to change the behaviour of the button, change the behaviour of the underlying method it calls based on different class members parameters.